# Can any one tell me the module used here

Tags: joomla, module, joomla-template

Can any one tell me the module used here..in this site on the right sidebar.
On hover it expands and floats as we scroll the page down.http://www.annualreport2011.wartsila.com/

I want to use with my joomla template. I searched but no luck..

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Joomla! website it's a [Crasmanager CMS](http://www.crasman.fi/en/) website.

Comment: but can I know the module used here I want to use it with my joomla website. @cppl

Answer (score 1):

You can try this module http://www.marcofolio.net/joomla/mfslidebar_sliding_sidebar_for_joomla_modules.html , Although i have not used this. You can also check a module from all these http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-panel/page2.There is no module found you can do this by jquery collapse menu or div.